# Smooth bell curve from N points javascript or php using 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc CanvasJs

Tags: javascript, php, 2d, bell-curve

I've been searching day and have found several examples but have yet to actually get a working formula to achieve what I'm trying to do. On the surface I though it would be rather easy but I have been proven wrong.

I have a php script that prints numbers 1-XXX-1 to create a pyramid shape.
For aesthetics I'm trying to smooth this into a bell curve.
I can provide the data as:
1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,2,1
or 1,11
or 1,2,3...,9,10,11

Every attempt I have made has ended in failure from increasing to a needle point and back to zero or a bell curve that ends negative etc..

I though I could write a simple function like:
function makeCurve (P1,TotalPoints) and iterate through it where the next point would be makeCurve (P2,TotalPoints) and when Px was naer 1/2 the total number of points it would slow the increase then begin counting down.

example for 9 points:
1, 1.3, 2.5, 3.3, 4, 3.3, 2.5, 1.3, 1 If it matters I'm using Canvas Js

Comment: It looks to me like you are simply trying to grab values off the Gaussian function. The function is described in details here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function

Comment: yes sir, I have read that several times now.